# laravel can't retrieve the ID after inserting a row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

This is my code

```
$model = Admin::create(Input::only('username', 'password', 'mobileNumber', 'firstName', 'lastName'));
                echo $model->username; 
                echo $model->ID;
exit;
```

After executing that code, I can see the new row in my table. but I just can see the `username` printed.

the `Admin` table already has an `ID` field which is the primary key and auto increment.

Comment: Try `dd($model->toArray())` and see what you get?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha do you mean echo dd($model->toArray()) ?

Comment: Without `echo`, only `dd(...)`.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I got `array(5) { ["username"]=> string(7) "asdfasdf" ["firstName"]=> string(5) "tonia" ["lastName"]=> string(8) "asdfasdf" ["mobileNumber"]=> string(11) "56456" ["id"]=> int(4) }` it seems that the `ID` becomes `id` right?

Comment: Are you trying to echo it in the `controller` ? It's there, make sure you have `exit;` at last, otherwise you won't be able to see it because the template will be loaded with `view`.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha yes I am in controller, I wonder why the `ID` becomes `id`. I will check if `id` is working. and will update u

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha the `id` works, but why is that happening please? the other colums still have capital letters

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha could you write an answer to accept it ?

Comment: If I am not mistake there is also a functionality like this `$id = Model::insertGetId(["username"=>"nicolas","email"=>"mail@example.com"]);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `ID` instead of `id`, since the `dd($model)->toArray())` shows:

```
array(5) { 
    ["username"]=> string(7) "asdfasdf"
    ["firstName"]=> string(5) "tonia"
    ["lastName"]=> string(8) "asdfasdf"
    ["mobileNumber"]=> string(11) "56456"
    ["id"]=> int(4) 
}
```

So, make sure you are using proper case in every `field` name and always try to use `lower case` field names in your table as well.

Comment: Thanks, but my column is `ID` not `id` and I have other coumlns like `firstName` which has a capital letter, so why in ID it is not working ?

Comment: it seems that it is a bug in laravel B-)

Comment: You should use `lower case` and `last_name` in field names but you are able to use `whereLastName('someName')` with `Eloquent`.

Comment: Because you have used `Input::only('username')`, it's in lower case in the form.

Comment: It seems you are expert in laravel, so please is there a way to set in the `create` method the column names? for example now I want to insert the `id` into another table. what should I do in the `create` function to tell it that this `id` should be inserted in the `adminID` field in the `customer` table?

Comment: You need to create the relationship method in your `Model`. Do you have [relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) between your current model and customer model ?

Comment: I have never heard of this relationship :) good you guide me to it. I will read about it, the customer table have an `adminID` column

Comment: I can't answer that in a comment, it requires some code and explanation, post another question and ask how to create a relationship with two tables and also provide both tables field information and relation type.

Comment: this relationshipt is like mvc .net 4.5. the exact same concept but with different syntax. many thanks

Comment: there is no need to ask another question now. first I need to understand the concept, do some examples, then if I fall I will ask and tell you. appreciate your time with me. you are great

Comment: Could you help me here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274903/laravel-insert-a-new-row-that-has-a-key-from-another-table-and-a-null-columns

Comment: Answered there, please check :-)