# laravel insert a new row that has a key from another table and a null columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

This is my restaurant table:

[image]

the restaurant table has a `adminID` field . and this is the admin table:
[image]

I have a form that has the values of both the restaurant and the admin,

This is Admin model:

```
class Admin  extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    public function restaurant(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Restaurant', 'ID');
    }
```

This is Restaurant model:

```
class Restaurant extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    public function admin(){
        return $this->hasOne('Admin', 'adminID');
    }
```

This is the RestaurantsController for storing a new restaurant

```
$input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, Admin::$rules);
        if($validation->passes()){
            $validation = Validator::make($input, Restaurant::$rules);
            if ($validation->passes())
            {
                $admin = Admin::create(Input::only('username', 'password', 'mobileNumber', 'firstName', 'lastName'));
```

as you see now I have the `$admin` variable,

#### My Question

what is the statmnet that I need to insert a new restaurant

1. please note that I can take the adminID from $admin->id
2. please note that the restaurant has a null columns like logo and addressManualID

Comment: I have the same problem...you have saved my efforts.

Comment: In case of editing your restaurant how you are displaying values of admin as we can just pass one model in the {{ Form::model ......}} tag. Are you passing values for admin in the controller?

Comment: @neeraj you don't need to pass `admins` when sending the restaurant model to the view because they admins would already (in a hidden manner) been sent. for example, you would say this in your view `$restaurant->admins()` and that is enough. Remember to build you relationship correctly

Comment: Many thanks !! it worked for me by adding like {{ Form::text('email',$event->admin->->email) }} as in my case event replaces restaurants :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you don't need to implement `UserInterface` and `RemindableInterface`  and and also don't use `use UserTrait, RemindableTrait`to create all of your models but only the `User` model if you have a `User` model for user authentication (log in/out). If the `Admin` model is being used as a replacement of the `User` model then you need to implement those interfaces and also need to use those traits as well. Also you need to explicitly declare the `protected $table` property to assign the table name which is being used for `Admin` model (If you are not using `User` model) and also you need to change some settings in `app/config/auth.php` file as given below:

```
'model' => 'Admin',

'table' => 'admins', // Could be anything else, same as protected $table property
```

Then try following to save the the related model when creating `Admin`:

```
//...
if ($validation->passes()) {
    $admin = Admin::create( Input::only('username', ...) );
    $restaurent = new Restaurant(Input::only(...));
    $admin->restaurant()->save($restaurent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still I need something. the `restaurant` table has `name` column, but the Input has `restaurantName` field, how to tell laravel to insert the `restaurantName` field in the `name` column

Comment: Make the array manually, `new Restaurant(array('name' => Input::get('restaurantName')))`

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha it seems you have helped my teammate too :) `user2208349` is my teammate and we are working on the same project

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha can you please suggest on my another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387300/laravel-ignore-validation-while-updating-record

Comment: Oh! Really glad to know that @AnastasieLaurent :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `associate()` method.

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::find(10);
$restaurant->admin()->associate($admin);
$restaurant->save();
```

Reference: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models