# Laravel ignore validation while updating record

Tags: validation, laravel-4

Validation for my model looks like:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'email' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required'
);
```

How can i tell laravel not to check the validation for "password" field if user is going to update the record and also i want to retain the previous password in the database until user fills the password again from the edit form?

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: I simply want that while creating a new record, both validations for email and password should be invoked but when that record is being updated then 'required' validation for only email field should be invoked. So i want to know that what should i write in the model to achieve it? The same thing was possible in RoR (Ruby On Rails) as laravel is inspired from RoR so just wondering how can i do it. Do i still need to post my entire code?